# Execute Gradle Task for Testing before Android (testing) build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, monkeyrunner

i have a Gradle Task that executes a monkeyrunner script for me. I need to add this task to the normal build process for testing. Inside the script i grant some permissions that are mandatory for testing and the testing output. I can't figure out yet how i can integrate or get the Gradle Task running before the Android Tests are starting. Is this possible? Can someone help me how i can do this? All those solution inside SO Threads didn't help me yet!

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You insert tasks into the task graph via [`Task.dependsOn()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:dependsOn(java.lang.Object[])). The user manual has [some examples](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks). That chapter also explains how to control the order that tasks are executed in.

The following is pseudo script because I don't know the names of the tasks in your build, but the solution should look something like:

```
check.dependsOn monkeyRunnerTests
androidTests.mustRunAfter monkeyRunnerTests
```

Note that this sample does not cause the monkeyrunner tests to execute when you run the Android tests. It only makes sure that *if* both sets of tests are due to run, then the monkeyrunner tests will come before the Android tests.

The sample also makes sure that when you run the `check` lifecycle task, the monkeyrunner tests execute.